Why are swimmers slower in shallow pools?
When I heard that swimming pools in the Olympics were slow due to shallowness ($\approx 2 \,\text{m}$ instead of $3 \,\text{m}$ deep), I thought it was due to the no-slipping condition, as for example in the usual Couette flow (see picture). These border effects also seem to be why side lanes are avoided in competitions.

However, reading about the Paris pools in Scientific American Is the Paris Olympics' Swimming Pool 'Slow'? Let’s Dive into the Math, it seems to be related to turbulence, wave reflection and all kinds of complicated dynamics that are hard to simulate due to the very nature of the Navier-Stokes equation.
Is saying that the no-slipping condition (and viscosity) is the cause of slow swimming  velocity an oversimplification? Are there more ingredients that are needed to be taken into account (aside from the psychological ones discussed in the SciAm article)?
